# How to import boxicons in node js

Tags: node.js, import, icons, node-modules

i have node js express app, i have installed the boxicons node package,

```
$ npm install boxicons --save
```

The boxicons package is installed in node modules, but i don't know how to properly import it and use it in all the views ejs files,
I tried in **app.js** to include it in either of the following ways,

```
import 'boxicons';

const boxicons = require('boxicons')

app.locals.boxicons = require('boxicons')
```

none of them worked, and they crashed the app.js with error.
Please help me with an answer

Update:
i'm using their css link in the head tag,

```
 <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

but it is slowing the website loading in production, that's why i avoid linking their unpkg css or script,

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your .ejs file

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
```

Now can use  any icon in your ejs file where you want

```
<box-icon type="solid" name="rocket"></box-icon>
<box-icon type="logo" name="facebook-square"></box-icon>
```

Comment: I prefer the above solution by Andrés because it uses the NPM installed by Adam (OP). The solution presented here makes the NPM package obsolete as it directly imports the .js file via CDN. If you follow this solution, make sure you add the css link as presented by OP in his update.

Answer (score 1):

to use locally, this worked for me, on the server add:

```
app.use("/icons", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../node_modules/boxicons")));
```

in view or html use:

```
<link href = "/icons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/icons/dist/boxicons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).